# Is it a good design to return SOAP message from RESTful service?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

My feeling is NO. I think such design combines drawbacks from both. Parameter size in RESTful is restricted by URL length and SOAP make heavy message workload compare with RESTful message. So is there any actual pros regarding such design?

Comment: Is this purely a matter of curiosity or do you have an existing scenario in which this is the case? I'd say in general it's probably not a good idea to mix REST and SOAP, but if you've come across a possible exception to that, I'd love to see.

Comment: I think you'll first have to explain what exactly you mean with RESTFul Service. REST is an Architecture Pattern whereas SOAP is more like a protocol. If you use your approach with SOAP over HTTP you can see that as Level 0 in the [Richardson Maturity model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html).